# is it possible to use swing/awt with blackberry/j2me?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, java

just want to know that if i can use swing/awt component with blackberry or j2me.

if yes how can i plugin it into eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it is not possible to use swing component with blackberry/j2me.Mobiles doesnt support swing/awt.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with Swing, you might like to take a look at LWUIT: http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/08/lwuit-for-swing-developers.html, which has Blackberry support (to some extent).

That said, ideally I'd go for native Blackberry UI.

Comment: yes lwuit works but you have to compile your code again for blackberry,and you can run some issues if you choose lwuit over native api.

Answer (score 1):

The blackberry UI APIs resemble swing/awt (including things like layout managers).  So swing code isn't directly usable but if you know swing you'll be at home.